# Do my squad mate's outfits affect their stats?

Tags: mass-effect-3

When I change my squad mate's appearance before a mission, does it affect their stats in the same way that changing my armor gives different bonuses?

Is there a list of the different choices?

[image: screenshot]

Though not shown, I am also referring to Kaidan and Javik.

Comment: Short Answer: Yes

Comment: @RavenDreamer I hadn't realized this until I read "For example Liara has increased Power Damage in her white Shadow Broker outfit, and Recharge Speed bonus when using her armor."

Comment: I hadn't realized this either, I thought that the outfits were purely cosmetic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes they do.

```
          Default        Alternate       N7 Pack       AshesDLC  
EDI        PD              PRS            n/a          Shields   
Javik      PD              PRS            n/a           n/a  
Liara      PD              PRS            PD            PRS  
Garrus   Shields            WD            n/a            WD  
James    Shields            WD          Shields          WD  
Ashely   Shields            WD           PRS             WD
Kaidan    PRS               PD            WD           Shields
Tali       PD              PRS            n/a            WD
```

All bumps are +25%, PD=Power Damage, WD=Weapon Damage, PRS=Power Recharge Speed.

[Values are summarized from the wiki.](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Squad_Members_Guide_(Mass_Effect_3)#Squad_Member_Outfits)

Comment: Damn! Until now I chose their outfits based on just how cool they looked in them. Now you ruined it all!

Comment: I knew, and I still picked what looked cool.  What's the point of saving the universe if you can't do it with a little style?